# What does "have discussed" imply in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

The module will incorporate a critical consideration of the concept of expertise and provide an opportunity for students to produce and ***have discussed*** their own communicative artefacts in the form of videos/blogs or other creative pieces.

Answer (score 1):

I had to read it twice to understand the sense, but it means that the students will be able to produce their own artefacts and *have them discussed* (presumably by the tutor and other students).

Comment: @Kate Bunting So it's not in the present perfect tense?

Comment: @Leon Ryu— It's an infinitive phrase— _to provide and (to) have discussed_, and infinitive phrases by their very definition are **untensed.**